# WinDbg Reverse Engineering Arguments

Tags: arguments, reverse-engineering, reverse, windbg, ida

I'm trying to debug an .exe that i'd normally run with this command line : ./problem.exe a.txt but i'm not really sure how to provide a.txt . I see the tab Arguments when i open the executable and i did write a.txt in there but doesnt seem to work . What's the exactly format of arguments ? All comand line ? Command line between quotes ? Just a.txt ? [image]

Comment: the file you are opening seems to be some .nam  is that an executable pe binary   putting a.txt in the edit box arguments should work if the binary expects a a.txt file in current working directory have you opened a cmd prompt in current working directory and tried  windbg problem.exe a.txt  does it work as expected

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command

```
.shell -ci "!peb" findstr "Current"
```

at the initial breakpoint, you'll find that the working directory of an executable started by WinDbg is actually the WinDbg directory. Certainly, `a.txt` is not in that directory.

Make use of the "Start directory" box and enter the path where `a.txt` is located (without file name).

[image: Start directory]